# JQuery Mobile Controlgroup Programmatic 'Checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a controlgroup made up of 3 buttons. I need to be able to set via JS which of the buttons is selected / 'checked'. I can do this via html markup by adding the checked attribute to the button I want selected as default. But, I can't find any means to actually change this via JS.

My HTML is simply:

```
<form>
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" id="searchType" class="center">
            <legend>Search By:</legend>
            <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="manufacturer" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Manufacturer</label>
            <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="updated" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Recently Updated</label>
            <input name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2c" value="featured" type="radio">
            <label for="radio-choice-h-2c">Featured</label>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

In terms of JS / JQuery, the only thing Ive been able to find was in relation to checkbox within a control group. This is as follows:

```
$( "#radio-choice-h-2c" ).prop( "checked", true ).checkboxradio( "refresh" );
```

Ive tried that via FireBug, but it doesn;t have any effect. I guess, since I dont have a checkbox, its to be expected. I also tried:

```
$( "#radio-choice-h-2c" ).prop( "checked", true )( "refresh" );
```

But, that was completely speculative.

If anyone has any wisdom to share on this, please do.

Comment: Have a look at AngularJs.

Comment: This should work with no issues whatsoever. When do you call it?

Comment: @Omar in an anon function placed at right before the closing div tag for the page content. I've also tried it in Firebug once the page has loaded.

Comment: You should get an error for running it this way, aren't you?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wWz9V/ use [jQM page events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/) ;)

Comment: I just tried that and on my project it just doesnt work. If I run it from the console in firebug, all I get is the response: 'Object[Document step1.html]' where the current page is step1.html It doesnt mean a lot...

Comment: Its odd, if I call this anywhere other than the anon function it works. Also, it doesn't work if I call it via Firebug. The anon function calls some JSONP data in from a remote site. How could this be affecting it????

Comment: you can call it within that function on success.

Comment: Oddly, it works calling it via '.done' too. Anyway, Ive got it done what I need it to do for now. Thanks!!